# How to apply the progress Bar dialog for login Checking in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Hai would like to display an progress  after the start the Checking the login form. I am not able to understand how to display it. i have listed part of my code below. Kindly please give an advice. Thanks.and am trying follow this tutorial [tutorial](http://www.ceveni.com/2009/09/sample-progress-bar-dialog-in-android.html).

**Update**

```
package com.android.cdtech;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
  public class loginForm extends Activity implements Runnable {
private TextView txt;
private ProgressDialog progDailog;
private TextView username;
private TextView password;
private Button sButton;
SoapObject request = null;
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
private static final String HostUrl = "xxxx";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "yyyy/";
private static final String methodname = "InsertCustomerInformation";
private HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(HostUrl);
private String check;
private Intent loginFormIntent;
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

final ProgressDialog pd = null;
Thread thread = null;
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         pd.dismiss();
         if (msg.what == 11) {
            sButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            sButton.setText("Login");
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String getImeNumber = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            String methodname = "CheckLoginRoles";
            String user = username.getText().toString();
            String pword = password.getText().toString();

            if (user.equals("") || pword.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Your Field is Emptry Please Fill all Fields ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            if (check.equals("Authenticated")) {
                try {


                    startActivity(loginFormIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception" + e.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + check + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            // Your code (for ex Toasting Message or passing
            // intents or displaying somthing....)
        } else if (msg.what == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + check + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            showNetworkAlert();
        }
    }

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    //super.onCreate(icicle);
    loginFormIntent = new Intent();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
    sButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            {
                if (isOnline(this)){//The method isOnline(Context) in the type new Handler(){} is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){})here i got Error
   {
                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                            "Loading...", true, false);(Error)The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean, boolean) in the type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (new 
   View.OnClickListener(){}, String, String, boolean, boolean)//
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {

                                calWeb();
                                handler.sendEmptyMessage(11);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("In Cache :");
                                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                } else {
                    messages.showNetworkAlert();//messages cannot be resolved
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showNetworkAlert() {

    builder
            .setMessage(
                    "Please check your internet connection.")
            .setPositiveButton(
                    "Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(
                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
    builder.setTitle("Connection Problem");
    builder.show();

}

public Boolean isOnline(Context context)        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void run() {
    calWeb();

}

private void calWeb() {
    SoapPrimitive response = null;
    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodname);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String getImeNumber = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    String methodname = "CheckLoginRoles";
    String user = username.getText().toString();
    String pword = password.getText().toString();
    request.addProperty("UserName", user);
    request.addProperty("Password", pword);
    request.addProperty("IMEINumber", getImeNumber);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    try {
        httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + "IService/" + methodname, envelope);
        response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        check = response.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
    }

};


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all You need to create handler above on click method

```
private ProgressDialog pd;
Thread thread = null;
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        pd.dismiss();
        if (msg.what == 11) {
            Your code (for ex Toasting Message or passing intents or displaying somthing....)

        } else if (msg.what == 0) {

        } else {
            showNetworkAlert();
        }
    }
};
```

then Creating progress Dialog in onCreate method

```
    if (isOnline(Your class.this)) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(Your Class.this, "", "Loading...", true,
                false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Calling your parsing method ....
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(11);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("In Cache :");
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    } else {
        showNetworkAlert();
    }
```

Create this method for Checking internet

```
public static Boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Displaying alert if Internet is not Present

```
public void showNetworkAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("Please check your internet connection.")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    builder.setTitle("Connection Problem");
    builder.show();

}
```

Comment: How i declare the value of message

Comment: Where i can pass the value message.(msg.what == 11),msg.what == 0)What is This i cannot underStood kindly guide me

Comment: In message.what == 11 , You are checking Your response is correct or not if Your Response is correct then Your are passing Intent of another activity..  Here Handler is common for this Activity so, You can parse another activity in same class then You can call handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); for another parsing...

Comment: You are just putting Your callWeb() to my run method and You are check condition for if(check.equals("Authenticated")) in handler's msg.what == 11 if condition and tell me it is working or not ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6277/discussion-between-leema-rose-and-rishi)

Answer (score 1):

I think this pattern could help you :

You can use:

- Async Task
- Handlers

## 1. Async task

```
      class WebTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void >{

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                webProgressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
                webProgressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
                if (!webProgressDialog.isShowing())
                    webProgressDialog.show();
                Log.i(TAG, "Progress Showing" +  webProgressDialog.isShowing());
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                  //Your Web request comes here make sure no ui operations coming here
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                if (webProgressDialog.isShowing())
                    webProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.i(TAG, "Progress Dismiss" + webProgressDialog.isShowing());
            }
    }

    //Calling task inside your coding..
     WebTask mywebTask = new WebTask();
     mywebTask.execute();
```

## 2. Handlers:

```
        Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == PROGRESS_SHOW) {
            progressDialog.show();

        } else if (msg.what == PROGRESS_CANCEL) {
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
        };};


     private static final int PROGRESS_SHOW = 22, PROGRESS_CANCEL = 21 ;
     //  PROGRESS_SHOW, PROGRESS_CANCEL are just have to be distinct int values


  .....this have to insert in your request part
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(PROGRESS_SHOW);
    new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      // <--------Here web request coming ---->
       handler.sendEmptyMessage(PROGRESS_CANCEL); // This should be here 
       //if not send message to handler progressdialog wont dismiss
       }
    }.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try following Code,

```
thisAct = this;  // onCreate Method , 
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show( thisAct, "Login", "Success..." , true, false );

                new Thread ( new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                        }
                        catch ( Exception e ) 
                        {  
                            Toast.makeText(thisAct, "DB Saving Error: " + e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

    private Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage ( Message message )
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
```